# Unwanted <p> tags in shortcode output. wpautop filter already removed

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, code-formatting

I've written a simple shortcode for Wordpress that outputs a group of  inside yet another  according to a particular content search.

Problem is, I keep getting this

tags in my output, which mess up my code a bit. While I can live with it, I can't live happily.

I have already added

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

in the "functions.php" of my theme. But the result is the same.

Shortcode code is as follows:

```php
$return = "<div class='tarimas-teaser-container'>";
$n = 0;
if ($wp_qry->have_posts()):
    while ($wp_qry->have_posts()): $wp_qry->the_post();
        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($wp_qry->post->ID), 'thumbnail');
        $return .= "<div class='tarimas-teaser-unit'><h4><a href='{$wp_qry->post->guid}'>{$wp_qry->post->post_title}</a></h4>";
        $return .= "<a href='{$wp_qry->post->guid}'><img src='{$thumb[0]}' width='{$a['ancho_img']}' height='{$a['alto_img']}' class='tarimas-teaser-img' /></a>$div_precio";
        $return .= "</div><!--tt-unit-->";
    endwhile;
endif;
$return .= "</div><!-- ttttt-container -->";

return $return;
```

I don't even have newlines on the constructed code. Yet I get this:

```html
<div class='tarimas-teaser-container'>
<div class='tarimas-teaser-unit'>
<h4><a href='http://www.tarimasterhurne.es/productos/roble-blanco-arena-1199020372/'>Roble Blanco Arena</a></h4>
<p><a href='http://www.tarimasterhurne.es/productos/roble-blanco-arena-1199020372/'><img src='http://www.tarimasterhurne.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/1199020372_main-150x150.jpg' width='100' height='100' class='tarimas-teaser-img' /></a>
<div class='precio mini'>10,93</div>
</div>
<p><!--tt-unit-->
<div class='tarimas-teaser-unit'>
<h4><a href='http://www.tarimasterhurne.es/productos/roble-marron-rojo-1199020368/'>Roble Marrón Rojo</a></h4>
<p><a href='http://www.tarimasterhurne.es/productos/roble-marron-rojo-1199020368/'><img src='http://www.tarimasterhurne.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/1199020368_main-150x150.jpg' width='100' height='100' class='tarimas-teaser-img' /></a>
<div class='precio mini'>11,03</div>
</div>
<p><!--tt-unit-->
<p><!-- ttttt-container --></p>
```

It's driving me crazy.
Again: I already removed wp_autofilter in functions.php.

Comment: Yes, some crazy plugin. I had this problem once. Check every plugin. Enable and Disable.

Comment: Yes.. that was quick. Apparently "shortcodes-ultimate" it's the guilty one on this case. Well, at least it didn't take long. Thanks!

Comment: It was this plugin: "shortcodes-ultimate".

By disabling "custom formatting" in its settings page, problem was resolved.

:P

Comment: have you checked this question http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13798/remove-empty-paragraphs-from-the-content

Answer (score 1):

Yes, some crazy plugin.

Check every plugin ... Enable and Disable every plugin

Comment: It was this plugin: "shortcodes-ultimate". By disabling "custom formatting" in its settings page, problem was resolved. :P